# Does the quality of steam affect the efficiency of a turbine to be calculated?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

We were presented in one of our lectures this problem.

A steam turbine operates adiabatically at a power level of 3500 kW. Steam enters the turbine at 2400 kPa and 500°C and exhausts from the turbine as wet steam with a quality of 97% at 20 kPa. What is the efficiency of the turbine? The efficiency I had first calculated resulted to a value of 0.81. Considering the quality of 97% however, I got 0.766. Was my understanding correct regarding the application of quality (dryness fraction)?

Our professor never got to explaining deeply what role quality had in such problems as the class ended quick.

Comment: Do you mean dryness fraction when you say quality?

Comment: @SolarMike, im sorry i wasn't able to clarify it, yes i meant dryness fraction

Comment: You just need to take the enthalpy at inlet and exit conditions and compare to the output.  Yes, the quality changes the enthalpy of the exiting steam.